# Spring access external properties-file in several places

Tags: java, spring, properties, resources

First question here, let's try this out.

I am using Spring 3.1.1 on a JBOSS 7.1.1 in Eclipse. I am also using Quartz 1.8.6.

I have had a problem for a while where I can't find my external properties-file in all classes of my application. I can find it and use the keys in the file in my controller-classes, and the temporary workaround has been to send the configurationfile as function parameters to access it in other classes.

The classes that I cannot access my properties-file (actually files) is threads to create for Quartz scheduler and in some model-classes. I guess I can't access it anywhere but in my controllers, but I have not tried all over. My project consists of several subpackages (se.xxx.xxx.xxx.status.*) where * is service, controller, model, scheduler, dao etc.

The property-file is defined as a bean in applicatoinContext as follows:

```
<bean id="statusConfigProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:resources/status-application-config.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I can load and use it successfully in my controllers with:

```
@Resource(name = "statusConfigProperties")
private Properties statusConfigProperties;
```

My thoughts is that this might have something to do with imports in some context-file, but I have looked for hours and not found anything. Searching has not giving me any answers to my specific problem, most questions regards just getting the bean to work, which mine does in the controllers.

When I try to access it in other classes in other subpackages, I get nullpointerexceptoins. Though only when I try to access a property (getProperty(String)).

Do anyone have any input to this?

Comment: Dependency injection will only work in spring managed beans. Objects created by quartz aren't sprnig managed and as such are injected and thus your properties remain `null`.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not only a Quartz-problem, I can't use the property-file in either of my pother subpackages, other than *.controller-package. For ex. I can't accesss properties in the file in my *.service-package, which would be needed. right now I send a reference using functoin parameters instead, but it is ugly and won't work everywhere ..

Comment: As long as it is a spring managed bean it would be accessible, if it isn't spring managed it won't be accessible. Make sure your services are spring managed and you don't create instances yourself. If you have a `@Resource` or `@Autowired`  and a dependency cannot be injected the construction of the `ApplicationContext` will fail. So my guess is you aren't using the spring managed instances but are constructing them yourself.

Comment: i think they are Såpring managed, since I don't instantiate them (see my original question where I use the resource). It works without problem in my Controllers but I must be missing something when there are classes in other packages involved ..

Comment: If you think they are spring managed you thus aren't sure... My guess still is they aren't because if you have a `@Resource` in those classes for the properties startup of your context will fail. At least there is too little information in your question to give an answer, please post additional classes and configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the input yesterday, it might have been a wednesday because things worked better straight away today. It ought to have been that the subpackage was'nt scanned correctly, it works now. Again, thanks for your time!

`To other with the similar problem:
1. make sure to component-scan the subpackages. 
2. Make sure that the bean works for the resource. 
3. Make sure that you have annotated the class.`

Comment: `COmponent-scan` already scans the subpackages (hence the name of the property `base-package`. BUt 2 and 3 are indeed valid, especially 3 if you use component-scanning.